# Advanced Search with Rails - Issue with Active Record SQl query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I built a search functionality on top of my rails app where I can search and filter based on the users's name & gender. The Search works properly, the only thing its not working accurately!

For example, if I search for male users the search results will also get me the female users. And I think this is because I'm using an ActiveRecord query where I compare the gender column of the users table with the params being inserted & because 'female' and 'male' are two very similar words, its getting results related to the two attributes. This the ActiveRecord query I used & that's working (not accurately though):

`"gender LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:gender]}%"`

So I used a different ActiveRecord query:

`"gender: %#{params[:gender]}%"`

The second query, unfortunately, breaks everything. I get this error in my terminal:

`SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (gender: %Male%))`

Those ActiveRecord queries are supposed to belong to the searches_controller of my 'search' model. This is my controller:

```
  def index
    if params[:username] || params[:gender].present?
        @search = User.where('true').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
        @search = User.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:username]}%") unless params[:username].blank?
        @search = User.where("gender LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:gender]}%") unless params[:gender].blank?
    else
        @search = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    end
  end

  def create
     @search = Search.create(username: params[:username], gender: params[:gender])
     redirect to @search
  end

  private

  def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:users, :gender)
  end
```

This is my the index of my search model, where I iterate on what's being searched (@search) and display in the search results:

```
<h1> Your Search Results </h1>

<% if @search.nil? %>
  <p> No Results Found </p>


<% else %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @search.each do |user| %>
    <%= user.name %>
    <%= user.gender %>
  <% end %>

</ul>

<% end %>

<p><%= link_to 'All Users',  users_path %></p>
```

This is a small video where I can explain what I want to do: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G5FYytvmdI6iKjmwlH16NeftGwsEnLQU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:
1) to match exactly a parameter you can do

```
@search = User.where(gender: params[:gender]) unless params[:gender].blank?
```

The rest you left is about the underlying LIKE clausa and if you want to do it with LIKE this is the right syntax

```
@search = User.where("gender LIKE ? ", "#{params[:gender]}") unless params[:gender].blank?
```

2) you are overwriting the @search variable, so if you have both the parameter, your name parameter query never remains. Try this in the end

```
@search = User.all
@search = @search.where("name LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:username]}%") unless params[:username].blank?    
@search = @search.where("gender LIKE ? ", "%#{params[:gender]}%") unless params[:gender].blank?
```

Comment: Do not interpolate the parameters for the prevention of SQL injection.

Comment: The sanitized versions of the variables in the second part of the array replace the question marks.

Answer (score -2):

Using `LIKE ?` is making your code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) so I definitely recommend you to change your approach.

I think you will solve the problem using something like

```
User.where("name = ? AND gender = ?", params[:username], params[:gender])
```

Also take the [Active Record Query Guideline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) as a reference every time you are using queries. You will find a lot of helpful stuff there.